# Regex help with splitting string

Tags: regex, split

I need to be able to parse strings like these:

```
kev-+kvs+-one-+gdl+-greg-+kvs+-two-+gdl+-les-+kvs+-three

-+gdl+-kev-+kvs+-one-+gdl+-greg-+kvs+-two-+gdl+-les-+kvs+-three

kev-+kvs+-one-+gdl+-greg-+kvs+-two-+gdl+-les-+kvs+-three-+gdl+-
```

and in all three cases recognise these three groups:

```
kev-+kvs+-one

greg-+kvs+-two

les-+kvs+-three
```

In other words, it should use the string -+gdl+- to split the string.

Assume that the sequence -+gdl+- will not occur except as a delimiter.

How would I write regex for that?

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I’ll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." -- Jamie Zawinski

Comment: I'm aware that I can split this - I was wondering if it was possible to do this using regular expressions. Your comment seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: *'And some people, when confronted with regular expressions, think "I know, I'll use a catchy quote that I remember". Now they have added nothing to the discussion.'* --Tomalak

Comment: @Shoko: it's not clear what you think a regex is. Regular expressions are not tools, they are just a way to describe patterns and they are *used* by tools (like split-like functions) to do stuff.

Comment: @Kemp, good point. I should have made myself clearer: I wanted to find out if it was possible to use the *match* method with a regex to find the groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with a regular expression, just use `-+gdl+-` as the pattern for the split. What needs to be escaped depends on your regex flavor.

EDIT after your comment: you can do it with a match but it adds unnecessary complexity. It also depends on the language, example in PHP

```
preg_match_all('/(.*?)(?:-\+gdl\+-|$)/', $string, $match);
```

you'll get empty matches though.

Comment: Thanks, kemp. I didn't know that $ could stand alone as part of a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to write a regexp for that just a split with the string you want as a separator, and you will get the field(s) wanted.

An example but i dont know what language you use

```
 "kev-+kvs+-one-+gdl+-greg-+kvs+-two-+gdl+-les-+kvs+-three".split("-+gdl+-")
```

Comment: In some languages, the only split(...) method there is, takes a regex (not a plain string). Take Java for example.

Comment: A plain string is a regex which happens to have no metacharacters

Comment: String.split("-\+gdl\+-") should work just fine in Java, you just have to escape it properly.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the regular expression you need is this:

```
-\+gdl\+-
```

The following Java code can do this, printing out the number of tokens and the tokens themselves:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "kev-+kvs+-one-+gdl+-greg-+kvs+-two-+gdl+-les-+kvs+-three";
        String regex = "-\\+gdl\\+-";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        String[] tokens = p.split(text);
        System.out.println("Found " + tokens.length + " tokens");
        for (String token: tokens) {
            System.out.println("Found " + token);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit verbose though, the three lines `String regex = "-\\+gdl\\+-"; Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex); String[] tokens = p.split(text);` could simply be written as: `String[] tokens = text.split("-\\+gdl\\+-");`

Answer (score 0):

Most regex libraries have split function. You just call this function with argument +gdl+ and it returns you an array. Details vary from language to language.

However, you don't even need regex. Many language libraries will have a function to split on "+gdl+". What language are you using?

Comment: As I said in my comment above to Andreas, I'm aware that I can split this. I wanted to know if it was possible to do using regex. Are you saying that it's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language you're looking for, but in Ruby you can just use `[String#split`][1](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000803) (and you don't need a regexp, a simple string parameter will do):

```
>> strings = ["kev-+kvs+-one-+gdl+-greg-+kvs+-two-+gdl+-les-+kvs+-three",
              "-+gdl+-kev-+kvs+-one-+gdl+-greg-+kvs+-two-+gdl+-les-+kvs+-three",
              "kev-+kvs+-one-+gdl+-greg-+kvs+-two-+gdl+-les-+kvs+-three-+gdl+-"]
>> split = strings.map {|s| s.split "-+gdl+-"}
=> [["kev-+kvs+-one", "greg-+kvs+-two", "les-+kvs+-three"], 
    ["", "kev-+kvs+-one", "greg-+kvs+-two", "les-+kvs+-three"], 
    ["kev-+kvs+-one", "greg-+kvs+-two", "les-+kvs+-three"]]
```

Note that this does have the problem of introducing null fields at the beginning or in the middle of your string. If you don't want any null fields, you'll probably have to filter those out afterwards:

```
>> split.map {|a| a.reject {|s| s == ""}}
=> [["kev-+kvs+-one", "greg-+kvs+-two", "les-+kvs+-three"], 
    ["kev-+kvs+-one", "greg-+kvs+-two", "les-+kvs+-three"], 
    ["kev-+kvs+-one", "greg-+kvs+-two", "les-+kvs+-three"]]
```

If you're not familiar with ruby, the `map` part is simply applying the same thing to each item in the array, so I can demonstrate how this applies to all of our examples.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what programming language you are using. If you are using high level programming languages such as java, python its pretty easy, as most of them specified, you would find a split function.

If you are using command line such as bash prompt, i would use sed

> $ str="kev-+kvs+-one-+gdl+-greg-+kvs+-two-+gdl..."
>
> $ for i in ``echo $str | sed 's/-+gdl+-/ /g'; do echo $i; done
>
> kev-+kvs+-one
>
> greg-+kvs+-two
>
> les-+kvs+-three
>
> kev-+kvs+-one
>
> greg-+kvs+-two
>
> les-+kvs+-threekev-+kvs+-one
>
> greg-+kvs+-two
>
> les-+kvs+-three

Or in Perl you can do slightly differently

> $ echo $str | perl -pe 's/(.*?)-+gdl+-/$1\n/g'